# Error: No named parameter with the name 'child' in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently reverse engineering a code developed by someone else. And even though slightly experienced to the Flutter world, not able to make sense of the error. Can help me in what needs to be done or which direction should look towards.

```
 showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          ***child***: Container(
                              height: 30,
                              width: 30,
                              child: Center(
                                  child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                                key: UniqueKey(),
                                radius: 20,
                                animating: true,
                              ))));
```

Error is

> Error: No named parameter with the name 'child'.
> child: Container(
> ^^^^^

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `builder` for creating **showDialog**

[image]

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context){
     return Container(
          height: 30,
          width: 30,
          child: Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                            key: UniqueKey(),
                            radius: 20,
                            animating: true,
                          ))));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below page for more reference related to showDialog https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlterDialog();
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return Container();
      },
    );
```

[showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) has no **child** parameter, use **builder** insted child